# What is the way to create a new column based on a different column in R?

Tags: r

```
outcome_1  outcome_2
1               0
0               1
1               0
1               0
0               1
0               1
1               0
0               1
```

existing column is `outcome_1`. How to create `outcome_2`?

Comment: `as.numeric(!df$outcome_1)`.

Comment: `df$outcome_2 <- (!df$outcome_1)+0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the variable `outcome_2` as:

```
df$outcome_2 <- 1 - df$outcome_1
```

Comment: Yes, as @docendo discimus has edited, if you have the information in a data.frame called `df` , this will be the correct way.